# Can "it" refer to or represent any element showing in the foregoing sentence?

Tags: grammar

> In human soul sensory capacities are as fundamental as intellectual
>   ones. It attain perfect goodness through many different powers
>   including both intellectual ones and sensory ones.

I use the first word of the second sentence “it” to refer to “human soul”
which functions as a part in an adverbial modifier. Is it ok?

Comment: user51369, yes, *it* is.

Comment: I would also add *the* before *human soul*.

Answer (score 2):

I think "it" is OK, but you should change attain to attains.